# How to use two dropdown menus to select variables for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have to make an alert that pops up after two options to fight that gives the results of the fight (*script.js* was provided).

When I select the two contestants, I can not figure out how to get the function to use the data in the script based on which two were selected.

Right now, when I click the button, I just get

> "contestant_1 vs contestant_2"

And an error in the console saying

> Uncaught TypeError: contestant_1.attack_power is not a function

```js
var mario_world = {
  mario: {
    name:"Mario",
    description:"Small and jumpy. Likes princesses.",
    celebration: "Mario wins and does a little dance",
    height: 10,
    weight: 3,
    speed: 12,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },

  bowser: {
    name:"Bowser",
    description:"Big and green, Hates princesses.",
    celebration: "Bowser wins and does a big roar",
    height: 16,
    weight: 6,
    speed: 4,
    boost: 0,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * (this.speed + this.boost);
    }
  },

  luigi: {
    name: "Luigi",
    desciption: "Mario's Brother. Wears green.",
    celebration: "Luigi wins and gives a thumbs up",
    height: 13,
    weight: 3,
    speed: 12,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },

  peach: {
    name:"Princess Peach",
    description: "Always getting captured",
    celebration: "Peach wins and twirls around",
    height: 13,
    weight: 2,
    speed: 16,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },


  boss_battle: function(contestant_1, contestant_2) {
    alert(contestant_1.name + " vs " + contestant_2.name);
    if (contestant_1.attack_power() > contestant_2.attack_power()) {
      alert(contestant_1.celebration);
    } else {
      alert(contestant_2.celebration);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="contestant_1" id="contestant_1">
    <option value="mario_world_mario">Mario</option>
    <option value="mario_world.luigi" selected="">Luigi</option>
    <option value="mario_world.peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="mario_world.bowser">Bowser</option>
  </select>
  <select name="contestant_2" id="contestant_2">
    <option value="mario_world.mario">Mario</option>
    <option value="mario_world.luigi">Luigi</option>
    <option value="mario_world.peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="mario_world.bowser" selected>Bowser</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Battle" onclick="mario_world.boss_battle(contestant_1, contestant_2);">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments you're passing to the `boss_battle` function (contestant_1, contestant_2) are strings, and you cannot use them to access the object properties.

Consider passing the names directly in your select options, and then accessing the various properties of `this`

```js
var mario_world = {
  mario: {
    name:"Mario",
    description:"Small and jumpy. Likes princesses.",
    celebration: "Mario wins and does a little dance",
    height: 10,
    weight: 3,
    speed: 12,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },

  bowser: {
    name:"Bowser",
    description:"Big and green, Hates princesses.",
    celebration: "Bowser wins and does a big roar",
    height: 16,
    weight: 6,
    speed: 4,
    boost: 0,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * (this.speed + this.boost);
    }
  },

  luigi: {
    name: "Luigi",
    desciption: "Mario's Brother. Wears green.",
    celebration: "Luigi wins and gives a thumbs up",
    height: 13,
    weight: 3,
    speed: 12,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },

  peach: {
      name:"Princess Peach",
    description: "Always getting captured",
    celebration: "Peach wins and twirls around",
    height: 13,
    weight: 2,
    speed: 16,
    attack_power: function() {
      return this.weight * this.speed;
    }
  },


  boss_battle: function(contestant_1, contestant_2) {
    alert(this[contestant_1.value].name + " vs " + this[contestant_2.value].name);
    if (this[contestant_1.value].attack_power() > this[contestant_2.value].attack_power()) {
      alert(this[contestant_1.value].celebration);
    } else {
      alert(this[contestant_2.value].celebration);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<select name="contestant_1" id="contestant_1">
  <option value="mario">Mario</option>
  <option value="luigi" selected="">Luigi</option>
  <option value="peach">Peach</option>
  <option value="bowser">Bowser</option>
</select>
 <select name="contestant_2" id="contestant_2">
  <option value="mario">Mario</option>
  <option value="luigi">Luigi</option>
  <option value="peach">Peach</option>
  <option value="bowser" selected>Bowser</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Battle" onclick="mario_world.boss_battle(contestant_1, contestant_2);">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There simply seems to be a bit of a misunderstanding of how objects work. You declared your object with a key `attack_power`, and assigned it to an anonymous function. To get the value from a `key-value pair` in an object, you simply have to reference the key attached to the object.

For example, if you have the object:

```
const obj = {
  fruit: 'apple'
}
```

to get the value of 'fruit' from `obj`, your code would be

```
const value = obj.fruit;
```

The same goes for functions assigned to a key in an object. To get the value (in this case, a returned value from a function) associated with the key, simply reference the key attached to the object.

---

Your code should instead look like this:

```
if (contestant_1.attack_power > constestant_2.attack_power) {
  alert(contestant_1.celebration);
} else {
  alert(contestant_2.celebration);
}
```